# Page with Category Returning 1

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories, pages, taxonomy

I am a beginner and looking for some guidance please.

I have added a function so I can have Categories for my Wordpress Pages

```
function my_page_category() 
{     
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
  add_post_type_support('page', 'category');
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_page_category' );
```

Now I need to display 3 pages (title and excerpt with read more) for only one category, and I have the below so far, but it is only returning 1 page, when I have 5 pages in that category.

```
<?php
$splash_page_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'posts_per_page'=> '3',
  'taxonomy' => 'category',
  'field' => 'slug',
  'term' => 'splash-homepage'
);

$splash_pages = new WP_Query($splash_page_args);

foreach ($splash_pages as $splash_page){  
?>

<h2><?php echo $splash_page->post_title; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $splash_page->post_content; ?></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

I have searched on wordpress and also tried in the array, without success:

```
'number'=>'3',
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

few things here:

1) Your WP_Query args doesn't look good, the proper way of querying posts by taxonomy should be:

```
$splash_page_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
             'taxonomy' => 'category',
             'field'    => 'slug',
             'terms'    => 'splash-homepage',
         ),
    ),
);
```

2) Is there any particular reason why you're using `foreach` instead of standard WordPress loop? If you want to keep using the foreach loop, then your posts objects are not in `$splash_pages` variable, look for them in `$splash_pages->posts`.

However, I'd recommend using WordPress loop like so:

```
if ( $splash_pages->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $splash_pages->have_posts() ) : $splash_pages->the_post();
    ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```